# How to convert datetime field from number to full month name

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```
                High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   year    pct_day
Date    month   week    day                             
1989-01-03  1   1   3   277.720001  273.809998  277.720001  275.309998  128500000   275.309998  1989    NaN
1989-01-04  1   1   4   279.750000  275.309998  275.309998  279.429993  149700000   279.429993  1989    0.014965
1989-01-05  1   1   5   281.510010  279.429993  279.429993  280.010010  174040000   280.010010  1989    0.002076
1989-01-06  1   1   6   282.059998  280.010010  280.010010  280.670013  161330000   280.670013  1989    0.002357
1989-01-09  1   2   9   281.890015  280.320007  280.670013  280.980011  163180000   280.980011  1989    0.001104
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2006-12-22  12  51  22  1418.819946 1410.280029 1418.099976 1410.760010 1647590000  1410.760010 2006    -0.005316
2006-12-26  12  52  26  1417.910034 1410.449951 1410.750000 1416.900024 1310310000  1416.900024 2006    0.004352
2006-12-27  12  52  27  1427.719971 1416.630005 1416.630005 1426.839966 1667370000  1426.839966 2006    0.007015
2006-12-28  12  52  28  1427.260010 1422.050049 1426.770020 1424.729980 1508570000  1424.729980 2006    -0.001479
2006-12-29  12  52  29  1427.000000 1416.839966 1424.709961 1418.300049 1678200000  1418.300049 2006    -0.004513
4539 rows × 8 columns
```

I used `data['month'] = data.index.month` to create and set the index to month number. Is it possible to reformat this so instead of number I can change it Jan Feb March format? The date still needs to be in datetime field.

I tried `data['month'] = data.index.month.format(month, '%B')` but am getting this error :

```
NameError: name 'month' is not defined
```

---

I want to the names to be changed to the plot which `df.plot(y='pct_day')`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from datetime import datetime
dateobj = datetime.strptime('2006-11-22', '%Y-%m-%d')

print(dateobj.strftime('%B'))
print(dateobj.strftime('%b'))
```

this will print

```
November
Nov
```

Comment: But this way the it will be changed to string `strftime`, is it possible that the output remains in datetime. I am trying to plot it and in the plot the x axis shows numbers for month and i want it to show Jan Feb.

Comment: you would have to do this conversion where you specify the labels for the diagram

Comment: Could you advise how i can do this conversion?